# dlls not detected

Tags: asp.net, dll

I created some .net dlls as component to my web application. When I added the reference through VS10, they got into BIN folder. But when I uploaded them on my web host, It doesn't seem to detect them (shows not found error). What additional do I need to do to make them detected? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you uploading them into the bin folder?

Comment: Yes, in the bin itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the exact error you are getting?  It could be that the new DLLs you uploaded to your server have a dependency on a DLL that doesn't exist on the server (that needed DLL could be in your GAC which is why it works on your machine).